# lightning design system toggle nested classes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, accordion

Im trying to use the following markup

```
     <lightning:accordion>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.faqs}" var="faq">
                           
                <lightning:accordionSection label="{!faq.Name}" class="tWrap >
                    <ui:outputRichText value="{!faq.Body__c}" /> 
                </lightning:accordionSection> 
             
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:accordion>
```

Im looking to override the app.css file with some custom css in the accordionSection so the text wraps and it doesnt truncate in smaller screens but I'm not being very successful.
the lightning:accordion is based on the [accordion](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/) from the lightning design system. The section I want to toggle in the markup is nested in the button attribute:

> class="slds-truncate" title="Accordion summary">Accordion summary<

```
.slds-truncate {
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Im trying to change "white-space" to "normal"

```
.THIS {
}

.THIS .tWrap {
white-space: normal;
}
```

Anyway I can achieve this or a different way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the slds-truncate class directly by adding the following to your CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-truncate {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: good point! ill try that..but wouldn't that override it in the whole component? how can I just localise it to an area?

Comment: If you want to localise it, add a class before it like this: .THIS .myclass .slds-truncate, and use "myclass" as a class on the actual accordion itself, it should traverse correctly that way!

Comment: Instead of having `!important`,  try increasing [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Thanks Rahul, will try that approach too it seems its more best practice when it comes to CSS

Comment: using @Timothy's approach I was able to specify elements a couple levels up and got it to work while avoiding !important

Thanks all